# Try to convert Time to Sec in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to convert Time to Sec but whatever I try I get error message.
The following query is what I done so far

```
                SELECT
                    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(mi.Time)),
                    uti.Date_
                    FROM 
                        users  ui
                    LEFT JOIN project_users  pui
                        ON(ui.UserID = pui.UserID)
                    LEFT JOIN user_timesheets  uti
                        ON(ui.UserID = uti.user_id)
                    LEFT JOIN moments mi
                        ON(uti.UserTimesheetsID = mi.UserTimesheetsID)
                    WHERE 
                        uti.user_id = 1 AND mi.Time != ''
                    AND 
                        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM uti.Date_) = '2020-01-21'
                    AND 
                        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM uti.Date_) = '2020-01-21'
                    AND 
                        mi.AtestStatus = 1                       
                    GROUP BY
                        uti.Date_
                    HAVING SUM(SELECT(TIME_TO_SEC(mi.Time))) > 28800;
```

I get error

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 74 Column: 36
```

I am not sure what to use here to convert, but so far I try to use `TO_CHAR` and `CAST`
The reference link is here

[REFERENCE](http://nimishgarg.blogspot.com/2014/10/oracle-convert-time-hhmiss-to-seconds.html)

Comment: Your Documentation reference is for MySql, not Oracle. Oracle does not supply such a function. Nor does it have a data type TIME. What is the data type for mi.time.

Comment: Yes, I just see that I post wrong documentation, but however I see that function TIME_TO-SEC does't exist in Oracle SQL, but is there another way how to make this work since I google it and most of answers are using TO_CHAR or TRUNC. 
Data Type of `mi.Time` is VARCHAR

Comment: Function `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ...)` returns an integer, thus comparison with `2020-01-21` is pointless. Consult the Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions.htm#SQLRF006

Comment: `!= ''` will never be true in Oracle. `SUM(SELECT(TIME_TO_SEC(mi.Time)))` contains a stray `SELECT` keyword. `JOIN` syntax has no brackets except in the special case of specifying a different join precedence (although they are just just redundant here, not invalid).

Comment: The are a couple of error here, not just this.

Comment: making mi.time a VARCHAR is almost certainly a design failure.  _Any_ proposed solution will now need to know the format of mi.time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You refer `TIME_TO_SEC` function from MySQL documentation though question is marked with `oracle` tag. Use `extract(second ...)` or google `oracle extract epoch equivalent`, depending on what you want.

Also the expressions `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM uti.Date_) = '2020-01-21'` and `EXTRACT(YEAR...` look suspicious, returned values definitely are not of form `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.